# How can make my mipmap subfolder auto folding in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, folding, mipmaps

The following is my android studio, and you can see the mipmap-*dpi folder is not folding.

[image]

here is the folding style:

[image]

i use android studio for a long time, but i still don't know how to fold it, so sad.

Comment: In your first screenshot, nothing is folding. You can see `drawable-...` and `values-...` directories as well as your `mipmap-...` directories. Please explain what is different about the `mipmap` directories in that screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a drop down menu at the top of projects window.

[image]

You are currently in `Project` view. Choose `Android` view to get the style you need.